# Fortran and OpenMP thread groups for independent tasks

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I need to run two independent tasks using OpenMP. One of them is way more involved than the other, so it would be ideal to split the available threads such that the more complicated task uses more of them. After these two tasks are finished, I need to use both of their outputs. I am not entirely sure if this can be done with OpenMP, so any suggestion would be very useful.

This is an attempt to illustrate what I need. There are two independent suboutines with separate inputs and outputs. Subroutine `mysub2` is more complex than `mysub1`. It has multiple nested loops, so it would benefit more from having more threads running it. Out of 6 threads, I would like to assign 2 of them to execute `mysub1`, and 4 of them to `mysub2`, simultaneously. After getting each subroutine outputs, `z1` and `z2`, both of them are used to compute `z3`.

In this attempt I was trying to assign threads 0 and 1 to task 1, and the other 4 to task 2. Obviously, this doesn't work as intended because it runs `mysub1` twice and `mysub2` four times, but I have no idea how to achieve what I need.

```fortran
module mymod
implicit none
contains
    subroutine mysub1(x1,y1,z1)
        ! Element-wise product of vectors
        real,intent(in)    :: x1(:),y1(:)
        real,intent(out)   :: z1(size(x1))
        integer            :: i
        !$omp parallel do private(i)
        do i = 1,size(x1)
            z1(i) = x1(i) * y1(i)
        end do
        !$omp end parallel do
        print *, 'Done with mysub1'
    end subroutine mysub1
    
    subroutine mysub2(x2,y2,z2)
        ! Matrix multiplication
        real,intent(in)    :: x2(:,:),y2(:,:)
        real,intent(out)   :: z2(size(x2,1),size(y2,2))
        integer            :: i,j
        !$omp parallel do private(i,j)
        do i = 1,size(x2,1)
            do j = 1,size(y2,2)
                z2(i,j) = dot_product(x2(i,:), y2(:,j))
            end do
        end do
        !$omp end parallel do
        print *, 'Done with mysub2'
    end subroutine mysub2 
end module mymod


program main
    use omp_lib
    use mymod
    implicit none
    integer           :: tid
    integer,parameter :: m = 2
    integer,parameter :: n = 3
    integer,parameter :: p = 4
    real              :: x1(m),y1(m),z1(m)
    real              :: x2(m,n),y2(n,p),z2(m,p),z3
    
    ! Setting total number of threads to 6
    call omp_set_num_threads(6)
    
    ! Assigning arbitrary values for illustration purposes
    x1 = 1.0
    y1 = 2.0
    x2 = 3.0
    y2 = 4.0    
    
    !$omp parallel private(tid)
        ! Getting thread number
        tid = omp_get_thread_num()
    
        if ((tid == 0) .or. (tid == 1)) then
            ! Task 1 to be executed in two threads, tid = 0,1
            call mysub1(x1,y1,z1)
        else
            ! Task 2 to be executed in four threads, tid = 2,3,4,5
            call mysub2(x2,y2,z2)
        end if    
    !$omp end parallel
        
    ! Using z1 and z2 (serially, no need to parallelize)
    z3 = sum(z1) + sum(z2)
    print *, 'Final output', z3
        
end program main
```

Of course, this is just an example. I know I don't need to use `mysub2` to do matrix multiplication. I'm just trying to illustrate that `mysub2` is more complex and hence, it would be ideal to use more threads for it, without having to paste several hundred lines of the actual code I have.

Comment: If you want to run it in parallel and synchronize the output ex-post, you should first save the strings and then sort them. You cannot magically synchronize `write` statements that happened before.

Comment: If you can run it serially, you can run it (maybe just the writing) in the right order, but it looses the point of parallelization.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава My actual problem is not about using `write` and synchronizing it. Maybe I chose a confusing way of illustrating it, but each subroutine actually is meant to perform several operations in parallel. For `mysub1` I would need fewer processors than for `mysub2`. After being executed, I need the output of both subroutines to do some extra operations.

Comment: You can't do the above - for a worksharing construct such as `$OMP do` all threads must go through it. Nested parallelism is probably one way to do this, tasks might be another, the devil is in the detail. But I find the question a little confusing, could you clarify what you mean by " I need to synchronize their outputs " and "This is an attempt that fails in doing what I need"

Comment: Please show the actual problem. Check [OpenMP teams](https://passlab.github.io/Examples/contents/Examples_teams.html). Disclaimer: I have never used them.

Comment: https://github.com/EPCCed/archer2-advanced-OpenMP/blob/2021-10-05/Slides/L02-NestedParallelism.pdf could be of use, the idea of nesting `!$omp do` within sections might be just what you want

Comment: Just updated the post with an example that I hope shows more clearly my problem